# Execute code every time the application begins

Tags: android, launch

I would like to execute code **every time** the application begins (not only
the very first time the application begins so **getSharedPreferences doesn't help**).

I've tried to write the code in onStart() of the main Activity, but that code was executed everytime I entered the activity including times I back to this activity from other activities (so **onStart() doesn't help**).

If someone can direct me with this, I'll appreciate that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an Application class - everytime an application opens it will execute the onCreate Method.

```
//Note extends Application and not Activity.
public class MyApplication extends Application {


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
   //Put your code here.
}
```

Make sure you register this in your manifest -

```
   <application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
```

Any code you put in onCreate will execute when the app is opened.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag,and that flag should be a public.

For example:

```
public boolean isFirstTime;
```

And your MainActivity's `Oncreate()`

```
if(!isFirsTime)
{ 
isFirstTime=true;
}else{
//do your stuff
}
```