# execute a function each time, when app started in ionic

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework to build my app, which seems working fine as per my requirement.

Now i close my app and reopen again it maintaining the state which is also fine.

Now my question is

1) Does app.js files run each time when my app is open ?
 i tried to add alert in app.js , which works only first time
  Is this right or wrong ?

2) I want to run a particular function each time when my app get started. Is there is any way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Is your being closed properly each time or just being backgrounded? Here's how you'd do it in Native app development - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533679/execute-code-every-time-the-application-begins/30533837#30533837

Comment: i dont knw. i am using hybrid app

Comment: If you hit the home button on your Android device/emulator the app is just backgrounded. If you hit "back button" until you exit app, the apps closed. Close the app and restart..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very large documentation which gets upgraded every time a new major version of Cordova/Phonegap is released. You can find that documentation here: [Cordova Documentation 5.0](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/)

It describes an event which is called every time your "device is ready". It is called `onDeviceReady`. To use this event you need an onDeviceReady-EventListener. The documentation for the EventListeners can be found here: [Events in Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#Events)

You can add that EventListener with this command:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

Like Zain described in the comments, there is a difference between exiting the application and pausing it, there is also another EventListener which gets called when the user pauses the application. It can be attached to your application with:

```
document.addEventListener("pause", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

So you could create a function which gets called when those two listeners are fired like this:

**onDeviceReady**

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceIsReady, false);

function deviceIsReady() {
    alert('Your device is ready!');
}
```

**pause**

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);

function onPause() {
    alert('Your application is paused');
}
```

Alternatively, if the alert is not called when the application is paused, you could add the [Cordova Plugin Console](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console) and call the `onPause` function with this content:

```
function onPause() {
    console.log('Your application is paused');
}
```

Please let me know, if this solves your question or if you need further assistance.